# Convert string representation of list to list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, eval

I have a string that looks identical to a list, let's say:

```
'[万福广场西,凰花苑]'
```

I would like to convert it into something like this:

```
['万福广场西','凰花苑']
```

I used `eval()`  and  `ast.literal_eval()` but got error as following:

```
y=eval('[万福广场西,凰花苑]')


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-0aadbead218c> in <module>()
----> 1 y=eval('[万福广场西,凰花苑]')

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name '万福广场西' is not defined
```

when using `ast.literal_eval()`,  I got this error `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000002A67FFA5CC0>`

Comment: You got `malformed node or string` because it does NOT look *identical* to a list, it only look similar.

Comment: `print( '[万福广场西,凰花苑]'.strip("[]").split(",") )` ?

Comment: @Stephen Rauch ok, how can I convert this to actual list?

Comment: @ Rakesh  thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eval() will consider the given string as python code and return the result. So as per your string, the python code will something like this `[万福广场西,凰花苑]` which means two variable `万福广场西` and `凰花苑` are in a list.

If you want it to be evaluated as a list of strings you need to bound both strings with `double quotes (")` such as

`'["万福广场西","凰花苑"]'`.

When you subject this string to eval(), the output would be,

```
['万福广场西', '凰花苑']
```

If you want this to happen dynamically, you need to use split and join functions like,

```
''.join(list('[万福广场西,凰花苑]')[1:-1]).split(',')
```

which first makes the list of strings given by

```
list('[万福广场西,凰花苑]')[1:-1] # O/P ['万', '福', '广', '场', '西', ',', '凰', '花', '苑']
```

then joins all the strings as

```
''.join(['万', '福', '广', '场', '西', ',', '凰', '花', '苑']) # O/P 万福广场西,凰花苑
```

and splits the string by `comma (,)` to create your desired output.

```
'万福广场西,凰花苑'.split(',') # O/P ['万福广场西', '凰花苑']
```

Hope you have got what you were searching for. Feel free to comment in case of any clarifications required.

Comment: @Sidhom Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Try Something like

```
my_list = '[万福广场西,凰花苑]'[1:-1].split(",")
```

It will return you an list -- `['万福广场西', '凰花苑']`

You can check it as -- `type(my_list) #<class 'list'>`

Answer (score 2):

Use `strip` and `split`

```
>>> '[万福广场西,凰花苑]'.strip('[]').split(",")
['万福广场西', '凰花苑']
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of your string isn't actually a valid list of literals because the literals are lacking the necessary quotes, so you can't parse it with `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()`.

Instead, you can use regular expression to parse the string into a list:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'[^\[\],]+', '[万福广场西,凰花苑]'))
```

This outputs:

```
['万福广场西', '凰花苑']
```